# Editing a Material UI row within React + Redux

Tags: datatables, react-redux, material-ui

I have a material UI table in a react project, and I want a user to click on the pencil/Edit Icon to edit the table row.

This is a loaded question, but would this require an additional piece of Material UI? what would the logic look like to make this happen?? I have most of the code set up on the backend, but don't know how to write this code in the component???

Thanks for looking!

```
//STYLE VARIABLE BOR MATERIAL BUTTON
const style = {
    margin: 12
    //
};




const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    user: state.user,
    reduxState: state.getExpense
});

class ExpenseTable extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            getExpense: []
        };
    }

      isSelected = (index) => {
        return this.state.selected.indexOf(index) !== -1;
      };

      handleRowSelection = (selectedRows) => {
        this.setState({
          selected: selectedRows,
        });
      };

    //on page load, DISPATCH GET_EXPENSE is
    //SENT TO expenseSaga which then
    //goes to getExpenseReducer and appends EXPENSE_DATA to the
    //DOM
    componentDidMount() {
        const { id } = this.props.match.params;
        this.props.dispatch({ type: USER_ACTIONS.FETCH_USER });
        this.props.dispatch({ type: 'GET_EXPENSE' });
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (!this.props.user.isLoading && this.props.user.userName === 
       null) {
            this.props.history.push('home');
        }
    }

    logout = () => {
        this.props.dispatch(triggerLogout());
        // this.props.history.push('home');
    };

    //SETS STATE FOR ALL INPUTS
    handleChange = (name) => {
        return (event) => {
            this.setState({
                [name]: event.target.value
            });
        };
    };

    //SUBMIT BUTTON- TRIGGERS DISPATCH TO EXPENSE SAGA TO ADD DATA
    handleClick = () => {
        console.log('add expense', this.state);
        this.props.dispatch({
            type: 'ADD_EXPENSE',
            payload: this.state
        });
    };


    //TRASH ICON-TRIGGERS DISPATCH TO EXPENSE SAGA DELETE
    handleClickRemove = (id) => {
        console.log('delete expense', this.state);
        this.props.dispatch({
            type: 'DELETE_EXPENSE',
            payload: id
        });
    };

    handleClickEdit = (row) => {
        console.log('edit expense', this.state)
        this.props.dispatch({
            type: 'EDIT_EXPENSE',
            payload: row
        })
    }

    render() {
        console.log('HEY-oooo expense render', this.state);
        let content = null;
        if (this.props.user.userName) {

      //MAP OVER REDUX STATE.

const tableRows = this.props.reduxState.map((row) => {

        //.MAP SEPARATES DATA INTO INDIVIDUAL ITEMS.

                const { id, item_description, purchase_date, 
                item_price, item_link } = row;
                return (
                    <TableRow selectable={false}>
                        {/* TABLE ROWS */}

                        <TableRowColumn>{item_description} 
                        </TableRowColumn>
                        <TableRowColumn>{purchase_date} 
                        </TableRowColumn>
                        <TableRowColumn>${item_price}</TableRowColumn>
                        <TableRowColumn><a href={item_link}>{item_link} 
                        </a></TableRowColumn>
                        <TableRowColumn><EditIcon class="grow:hover" 
                        onClick={() => {this.handleClickEdit(row)}} /> 
                        </TableRowColumn>
                        <TableRowColumn><TrashIcon onClick={() => 
                         {this.handleClickRemove(id);
                        }}/>
                        </TableRowColumn>
                    </TableRow>

                    // END TABLE ROWS
                );
            });

                <div>
                    {/* FORM FOR ADDING EXPENSES(DATA) */}

                    <form id="expenseForm">
                        <h3>
                            Add a new <br />
                            expense
                        </h3>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="fname"
                            name="fname"
                            placeholder="Item description"
                            onChange= 
                            {this.handleChange('item_description')}
                        />

                        <br />

                        <br />
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="lname"
                            name="lname"
                            placeholder="Item price"
                            onChange={this.handleChange('item_price')}
                        />
                        <br />
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="lname"
                            name="lname"
                            placeholder="Item link"
                            onChange={this.handleChange('item_link')}
                        />
                        <br />

                        {/* END FORM */}

                        <RaisedButton
                            id="expSubmit"
                            label="Submit Expense"
                            primary={true}
                            style={style}
                            onClick={this.handleClick}
                        />
            {/* TABLE TOTAL KEEPS CURRENT TOTAL OF PRICE COLOUMN */}

                        <h1>Total:</h1>
                        <br />
                        <h3>$748.93</h3>
                    </form>


          {/* TABLE HEADERS */}
                    <Table>
                        <TableHeader>
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableHeaderColumn>Item 
                                 description</TableHeaderColumn>
                                <TableHeaderColumn>Purchase 
                                 Date</TableHeaderColumn>
                                <TableHeaderColumn>Item 
                                Price</TableHeaderColumn>
                                <TableHeaderColumn>Item 
                                Link</TableHeaderColumn>
                                <TableHeaderColumn>Edit 
                                entry</TableHeaderColumn>
                                <TableHeaderColumn>Delete 
                           entry</TableHeaderColumn>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableHeader>

                        <TableBody>
                            {tableRows}
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <Nav />
                {content}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// this allows us to use <App /> in index.js
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ExpenseTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

The default material-ui table doesn't have the feature of in-line editing. You will have to write your own wrapper to achieve this which can be time consuming. To overcome the time issue we can use some good existing libraries.
Here's one powerful library from DevExtreme for the same which i used, but go through their licensing before you take the final decision to use.

https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/demos/featured/controlled-mode/